# Can you say ETA to mean "estimated time of arrival" (heure d'arrivée estimée) in North American French?

Tags: québec

Is the English acronym ETA "estimated time of arrival" ever used in North American French varieties (e.g. Canadian French spoken in Montreal) to stand in for *heure d'arrivée estimée*?

Comment: They would understand it, but I would stick to _heure d'arrivée estimée_ :-)

Answer (score 3):

No, ETA is not generally used by French Canadians, at least in Quebec. Instead, words indicating approximation are used when communicating arrival times, such as "*j'arrive dans environ 15 minutes*" or "*on va être là vers 10 heures*".

Some groups of people who also speak English and/or know the acronym and know they will be understood might use it, but it's not the majority. I am from Montreal, and even after I learned what ETA meant (which was fairly late considering how long I've spoken English), I never used it and I can't recall anyone else using it either. It's however possible that people from other communities where English is a lot more present, such as in Louisiana or even to some extent in Acadie, would understand and use it more frequently.

Answer (score 2):

A Canadian French acronym looks to be **HAP** although it doesn't look widely used/understood, outside perhaps in the professional transportation jargon (air, sea, land and rail). It also clashes with the more common *heure avancée du Pacifique*.

e.g. from http://pilotes.quebec/forum/viewtopic.php?t=11467&p=175165

> Lors de ce premier appel téléphonique au CDT, le pilote doit fournir les renseignements suivants à l'ASFC :
>
> **l'heure d'arrivée prévue (HAP)**;
> le numéro d'immatriculation ou le suffixe numérique de l'aéronef;
> le nom au complet, la date de naissance et la citoyenneté de toutes les personnes à bord;
> ...
> Si **l'HAP** change de plus de 30 minutes ou s'il y a des changements concernant le point d'arrivée, la liste des passagers ou les déclarations de ces derniers, le pilote doit en aviser le CDT avant l'arrivée au Canada.
>
> Le pilote doit demeurer au point d'arrivée jusqu'à ce que **l'HAP** déclarée au CDT soit passée.
> Il n'a pas besoin de faire un second appel au CDT. Si aucun agent n'attend l'aéronef lorsque ce dernier arrive à **l'HAP** déclarée ou à l'heure d'arrivée réelle, selon la plus tardive de ces deux heures, l'aéronef peut se rendre à sa destination finale où les passagers pourront descendre.

Also: http://www.manitoulintransport.com/index.php/fr/glossaire.html http://www.hsmaritime.com/fr/ports/sept-iles/

***Heure d'arrivée prévue*** is the usual translation for "estimated time of arrival". A simpler one is also ***arrivée prévue à***.

Comment: I understand HAP more as *heure avancée du Pacifique* than *heure d'arrivée prévue*.